# How to prevent one file from being a Trusted Document?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I created an Excel-file with a limited amount of VBA.and it has to be accessible for several people. When some people click on "Enable" macro's and make it a trusted document, it does not work for others anymore.

So, is there a way to prevent this specific file from being a Trusted Document? I know I can adjust my trust settings, but I cannot do this for all other employees. Is there a way to adjust the file-specific characteristics?

Comment: I used e.g. this little Macro (Function GetUserName(), GetUserName = Application.UserName, End Function) to retrieve someone's Username to show his results. Apparently this does not show the username from the moment one user enables the macro (and therefore makes it a trusted document).

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what you mean by "it does not work for others"? Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1408436/edit) instead of adding information in comments